# Problem running Hyperledger Fabric network on Ubuntu 18.04 - BYFN.SH Up

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I get stuck after running " ./byfn.sh up ". The end-to-end testing does not reach the end. I get stuck at the following:

Querying chaincode on peer0.org1... ===================== Querying on peer0.org1 on channel 'mychannel'... ===================== Attempting to Query peer0.org1 ...3 secs

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'

That is as far as it gets. I have installed all the requirements using root permission. Reinstalled everything, purged containers, and restarted the system many times and always get the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add some more logs. It's not clear what actually happened

Comment: Everything else was fine until it reaches this point. No prior error messages. I am running this on Ubuntu 18.04. Then it just hangs. After 30 min, 1 hour, 2 hour ... just remains stuck at this part of the end-to-end testing. I have tried on different regions and AZ, no luck on any of them. Do I need to change the version of Hyperledger I am trying to install?  I am using hyperledger 1.4.7 1.4.7 0.4.20.

Comment: yes, you can try latest `v2.2` but i don't think it is related to version

Comment: I just tried a different version of Hyperledger, much earlier than the one I was trying to install and it worked. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to complete the end-to-end testing of the network.

Installing chaincode on peer1.org2...

- peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l golang -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
- res=0
- set +x
  2020-08-21 06:52:43.808 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
  2020-08-21 06:52:43.808 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
  2020-08-21 06:52:44.208 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
  ===================== Chaincode is installed on peer1.org2 =====================

Querying chaincode on peer1.org2...
===================== Querying on peer1.org2 on channel 'mychannel'... =====================
Attempting to Query peer1.org2 ...3 secs

- peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
- res=0
- set +x

90
===================== Query successful on peer1.org2 on channel 'mychannel' =====================

========= All GOOD, BYFN execution completed ===========

---

| ****| | \ | | |  _ \

|  *|   |  | | | | | |
| |***  | |\  | | |_| |
|**__*| |*| _| |____/

Solution, use an earlier version than the one I had indicated earlier. In this case I used curl ... bash -s 1.2.0.

The reason I am doing this is because the latest hyperledger version does not use the BYFN.SH example that is used in most tutorials. Hyperledger updated it to something totally different. Now I can work with previous tutorials and moving forward, the latest version.